# HTML input field datatype issue

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have an issue with input fields. I have 2 input field type="number" and I would just like to add those 2 number together.
My input fields

```
<input type="number" name="a" id="a" onchange="add()">
<input type="number" name="b" id="b" onchange="add()">
```

This is my js file

```
function add() {
var a = document.getElementById("a").value;
var b = document.getElementById("b").value;
var c = a + b;
}
```

Issue is when I try 20+20 result is 2020, not 40 as I would expect.

Comment: Input values are strings.  Even if the type is number.

Comment: Use `parseInt(a)+parseInt(b)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `parseInt()` function to convert the string to an integer

Comment: @Tom btw, the correct usage is to also pass in the radix, eg: `parseInt(a, 10)`

Answer (score 0):

as stated in the comment, all values from inputs are strings, so you need to

```
function add() {
var a = parseInt(document.getElementById("a").value);
var b = parseInt(document.getElementById("b").value);
var c = a + b;
}
```